# Who developed Stepwise project planning?

Tags: planning, prince2

In book "Software Project Management" by Bob Huges on Chapter 3: Project Planning, it describes an approach called "Stepwise Project Planning" in contrast to PRINCE2 approach which was developed in UK as a government standard for information system projects.

[image]

There is a good history about PRINCE2 which can be read on Wikipedia or [prince2.com](https://prince2.com).

What I am curious about is: Where did Stepwise approach come from. who developed it and how it is different? I read some articles on web but there is no clear answer to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My academic research skills came in handy. The answer is Robert Tamblyn Hughes (also the author of the book you referred to, I believe) in 1996. He published a conference paper titled "The 'Step Wise' Planning Approach to Software Projects."

Check out this link: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3630458_The_step_wise%27_planning_approach_to_software_projects

If you read that 3 page article, it clearly states how is it different to PRINCE.

Please tell me this is not for a school project!?